# .delay doesn't seem to delay .fadeOut/.fadeIn

Tags: jquery, delay

I'm having an issue with the following line of code.

```
$("#chicken").delay(scrolllen).fadeOut(0).removeClass("flipped").css({ left: 900 + "px" , top : 2370 + "px"}).fadeIn(0).animate({ left: 1500 + "px" , top : 2370 + "px"}, 5000, 'linear');
```

So I'm having other animations happen.  They take `scrolllen` so I have the delay so that it waits for the end of that animation.  Then the item house vanish from where it is.  The problem is, the `.fadeOut` is occuring immediately so I see the item vanish.  Is there another way to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/8dAqz/

Comment: *"PLEASE don't ask for a JSFiddle as I really don't think it's needed."* **Strongly** recommend removing that statement if you really want help. (Also recommend adding a fiddle or http://jsbin.com, but it's optional, your question is fairly clear without it.)

Comment: Why use `.fadeOut()` with a time of `0`?

Comment: Because I am too lazy to use `.css({display:none})`

Comment: On looking deeper, the problem seems to be the "effects queue".  Looks like I need to know what counts as that.

Comment: If you're lazy, the shortcut to `.css({display:none})` is `.hide()` - even fewer characters to type than `.fadeOut(0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have resolved this an alternate way.

http://jsfiddle.net/8dAqz/1/

By using the javascript function `setTimeout` and encompassing the jQuery calls within it, it stops as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kqwrm/1/ `grr, hate the code requirement`

While your code does the animation for the red square, I think what you meant to do is sort of what green square does (still, doing fadeOut and fadeIn simultaneously doesn't have much effect).

Now, the question is - what is exactly that you want to happen?

Comment: I don't see fading happening in this example for some reason.  I've modified your example to match mine more correctly.  http://jsfiddle.net/8dAqz/.  As you can see, delay only seems to delay the `.animation`.

Comment: @Splatter - what your code will do, is:
the original - delay execution of all animations for scrolllen ms, execute fadeOut immediately, move to left by 900px immediately, fadeIn immediately, then move to left to 1500px with linear animation lasting 5000ms.